# Данные формы не передаются в файл

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование

**Сам сайт:** [Сайт](https://se.ifmo.ru/~s264431/index.html)

Проблема в том,что данные из формы index.html не передаются в handler.php
Код файла index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Сайт</title>
   <style>
  
   body 
   {
    background: #f6e8d7;
   }
   #helpMe
   {
    
      background: #f0f0f0; 
    width: 400px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000; 
 
   }
   input[type="submit"] 
   {
   
    border: 4px inset #100;
     cursor: url(WorldOfWarCraft/arrow.cur),pointer;
    
   }
   p b
   {
    color:orange;
    border: 1px inset #100;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background: #808080;
    outline-style: outset;
   }
   img.rightfoto
   {
 margin: 0px; 
 float: right ;
   }
   .active {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
  </style>
 </head>


   
 <body>
<img class="img.rightfoto" src="image.png" " >
 <form method="GET" action="handler.php" class="formWithValidation" style="float: left;">


  <fieldset class="fieldset" style="width: 400px;">
 <h3 style="font-family: fantasy;font-stretch: inherit;font-weight: 0;" >ЗАГОЛОВОК </h5>
 <h5> 210001 <h3>
  <p><b name="textX"> X</b>         </p>


    
     <div id="helpMe"> 
     
      <input type="button" class='checkboxxx'  name="InputX" value="-2"> 
    <input type="button" class='checkboxxx' name="InputX" value="-1.5">
    <input type="button" class='checkboxxx' name="InputX" value="-1">
    <input type="button" class='checkboxxx' name="InputX" value="-0.5">
    <input type="button" class='checkboxxx' name="InputX" value="0">
    <input type="button" class='checkboxxx' name="InputX" value="0.5">
    <input type="button" class='checkboxxx' name="InputX" value="1">
    <input type="button" class='checkboxxx' name="InputX" value="1.5">
    <input type="button" class='checkboxxx' name="InputX" value="2">
     
    </div>
    
    <Br>
   
   
 <p><b> Y</b></p>
           
    <p><input type="text" class="Y"  maxlength="5" size="6" name="InputY" placeholder=" От -3 до  3"></p>
   
 
 <p><b> R</b></p>
 <p>
         <p><input type="text" class="RRR"  maxlength="5" size="6" name="InputR" placeholder="  От 1 до  4"></p>
 
   
    </p>
 <p><input type="submit"   class="validateBtn" ></p>
    </fieldset>
    
</form>

  <script>
  var SMSx;
  var SMSy;
  var SMSr;
  var conditionX=0;
  var form=document.querySelector('.formWithValidation');
  var button=document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxxx');
for (var buttoned of button)
 {
  buttoned.addEventListener('click', function (event) 
 {
         var X=event.clientX; 
  var Y=event.clientY;
         button.forEach(i =>
   i.classList.remove('active'));

  
        this.classList.toggle('active');
 });
};



    function showError(container, errorMessage) {
      
     var msgElem = document.createElement('span');
      msgElem.className = "error-message";
      msgElem.innerHTML = errorMessage;
      container.appendChild(msgElem);
      
    }
 
    function resetError(container) {
            if (container.lastChild.className == "error-message") {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
      }
    }
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) 
    {
    resetError(document.querySelector('.fieldset') );

      var elems = form.elements;
      if (elems.InputY.value) 
      {
        var reg=/^\d+[,]\d*$|^\d+$/ ;
    if(reg.test(elems.InputY.value))
    { 
            SMSy=""
    }
                                else 
    {
     SMSy="Ошибка заполнения Y";
     event.preventDefault() ;

    }
    
        
      }
      else
      {
         SMSy=" Заполните Y <Br>";
         event.preventDefault() ;
      }
      
      if ((elems['InputX'][0].classList.contains('active'))||(elems['InputX'][1].classList.contains('active'))||
      (elems['InputX'][2].classList.contains('active'))||(elems['InputX'][3].classList.contains('active'))||
      (elems['InputX'][4].classList.contains('active'))||(elems['InputX'][5].classList.contains('active'))||
      (elems['InputX'][6].classList.contains('active'))||(elems['InputX'][7].classList.contains('active'))
      ||(elems['InputX'][7].classList.contains('active')))
      {
          SMSx=""
            
     }
        else
        {
          SMSx="<p style=\"font-size: 120%; font-family: monospace; color: #cd66cc\">Заполните  X </p> ";
            event.preventDefault() ;
         }
         if (elems.InputR.value) 
        {
                                var reg=/^\d+[,]\d*$|^\d+$/ ;
    if(reg.test(elems.InputR.value))
    { 
           SMSr=""
    }
                                else {
        SMSr="Ошибка заполнения R";
                     event.preventDefault() ;

       }

        
         }
          else
                    {
                      SMSr=" Заполните  R <Br>";
                      event.preventDefault() ;
                    }
        showError(document.querySelector('.fieldset') , SMSx+SMSy+SMSr);
      });
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Исходный код handler.php :

```html
<html>

 <head>

  <title>Тестируем PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php

 if (!empty($_GET["InputX"])&&!empty($_GET["InputY"])&&!empty($_GET["InputR"])) 
 { 
     $X=$_GET["InputX"];
  $R=$_GET["InputR"];
  $Y=$_GET["InputY"];
  echo " Получены новые вводные: имя ".$_GET["InputX"].", возраст  ".$_GET["InputY"]." лет и ".$_GET["InputR"]." ";
  
     if(($X>-$R&&$X<0&&($Y>-$R)&&($Y<0))||($X<$R/2&&$X>0&&($Y>-$R/2)&&($Y<0)&&($X^2+$Y^2<$R/2*$R/2))||(($Y<$R)&&($X<$R/2)&&($Y<-2*$X+$R)))
  {
   echo " <b>Проверка пройдена.Точка попадает в график</b>";
   
  }else{ 
           echo " <b>Проверка не пройдена.Точка вне графика</b>";
  }
  
 } 
 else
 { 
     echo "Переменные не дошли. Проверьте все еще раз.";
 }
 

?>
<form method="GET" action="index.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Повторить ввод">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные передаются,но не все - значение поля типа `<input type="button">` не будут передаваться на сервер, и из-за вашего условия

```
 `if (!empty($_GET["InputX"])&&!empty($_GET["InputY"])&&!empty($_GET["InputR"]))`
```

вы получаете

```
echo "Переменные не дошли. Проверьте все еще раз.";
```

Что бы передать значения из type="button" можно воспользоваться скрытым полем. И при клике на кнопку передавать в него значение.

```
    <input type="button" onclick="change(1)"></input>
    ...
    <input type="button" onclick="change(3)"></input>

    <input type="hidden" id="InputX" name="InputX" value="" />

    function change(value){
        document.getElementById("InputX").value= value;
    }
```